# VBA: type mismatch error with FunctionaArray

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Getting a type mismatch(run time error 13) on this code and I am unable to solve it.

```
LastWeek = 10
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = LastWeek + 1
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, _
        ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaArray _
        = "=INDEX(R2C5:R81C10, MATCH(R4C12&R4C13&R3C15,R1C2:R81C2&R1C3:R81C3&R1C4:R81C4,0)-1,MATCH(R4C14,R1C5:R1C10,0))" / "=INDEX(R2C5:R81C10, MATCH(R4C12&R4C13&R3C15,R1C2:R[72]C2&R1C3:R[72]C3&R1C4:R[72]C4,0)-1, 1)" * 100
```

I am stuck with this part for a long time now and out of clue to solve it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why u use quotes in formula text before and after "/" and "*"?

You looking for this formula?

```
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, _
        ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaArray _
        = "=INDEX(R2C5:R81C10, MATCH(R4C12&R4C13&R3C15,R1C2:R81C2&R1C3:R81C3&R1C4:R81C4,0)-1,MATCH(R4C14,R1C5:R1C10,0))/INDEX(R2C5:R81C10, MATCH(R4C12&R4C13&R3C15,R1C2:R[72]C2&R1C3:R[72]C3&R1C4:R[72]C4,0)-1, 1) * 100"
```

Comment: It is basically formula1 / formula2 * 100. If I keep only formula1 or formula2 (including the quotes) alone, it seem to populate the desired cell with the value. However, on trying to use both the formula's together, it is giving me the error.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey C. Thats what I wanted. :)